# svn checkout for 20thingsilearned

Tags: tortoise-svn, checkout, google-code

I am trying to checkout the code at [googlecode](http://code.google.com/p/20thingsilearned/source/checkout) for the project 20thingsilearned, however I am getting the same error on Tortoise SVN and cygwin in Windows 7

```
Error: OPTIONS of   
Error: 'http://20thingsilearned.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/%2020thingsilearned-read-only':   
Error: could not connect to server (http://20thingsilearned.googlecode.com)
```

Appreciate your help.

**EDIT:** I used http://downloadsvn.codeplex.com/ and it works like a charm, problem solved.

Comment: I configured the firewall to allow the tortoise connections, but in vain.

Comment: Can you access http://20thingsilearned.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ in your web browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of it the command they are giving you is a full SVN console command to check out the repository.

> `# Non-members may check out a read-only working copy anonymously over HTTP.`
>     `svn checkout http://20thingsilearned.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ 20thingsilearned-read-only`

Which would check out the repository at `http://20thingsilearned.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/` to the folder `"20thingsilearned-read-only"` while your error is that Tortoise is trying to checkout the full path of 'http://20thingsilearned.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/**%2020thingsilearned-read-only**'  which does not exist.

If you are using Tortoise SVN then simply check out

> http://20thingsilearned.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/

to your working directory.

Comment: I tried that also, but it didn't work

Comment: @RaviGupta What did the error show when you tried?  I've clarified my answer slightly.